# apache ubuntu 18.04 ads trailing slash at the end automatically

Tags: server, apache2, php, uninstall, lamp

first i enabled mod rewrite then i used in my .htaccess this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

virtual hosts file is a standard installation of LAMP

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/webtrade
```

i have been trying various combinations in my .htaccess file but none worked
when i access a link like *domain/something* it automatically becomes *domain/something/*
with a forward slash.

Comment: Please be aware that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which was released in 2018-April (thus the 18.04) had 5 years of *standard* support life, is nearing the end of those five years. You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm if your system is still *supported*. Either way, if the machine is on-line, you should plan to *release-upgrade* asap unless you plan to use ESM/Pro, but please note ESM/Pro releases are not on-topic here when standard support ends (May-2023).

Comment: Are you certain the problem is Apache and not: (0) the site code (1) the browser (2) stale cache ? 

Comment: This is literally the last day (May 31st) that Ubuntu 18.04 has standard support. As of tomorrow, 18.04 is no longer supported here. Perhaps you should consider updating.

Comment: No. sites ok i have ported it from xampp

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved i added the directory to *apache2.conf* with

```
<Directory /var/www/webtrade>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS did a distribution upgrade from 18.04. automatic forward slash was gone
Problem solved!!!

Comment: Please someone check my answer. Thanks